# How do I add my array dates into the datediff calculation

Tags: arrays, bash, average, datediff

Newbie to bash scripting here and could use some help on this if you have time. My customers upload and each has a datestamp in filename like this:

```
* 20170815041135 
* 20170820041135 
* 20170823071727 
* 20170826040609   
* 20170828050704 
* 20170830153011
```

I need to calculate the number of days between each upload then find the average interval of the listed uploads

I can find the date difference between two dates with this command

```
echo $(( ($(date --date="20170831" +'%s' ) - $(date --date="20170821" +'%s')) / (60*60*24) ))
```

## gives 10

To do multiple dates I've read that I need an array, so here is my range of upload dates in an array.

```
array=( `20170830153011`,`20170828050704`,`20170826040609`,`20170823071727`,`20170820041135`,`20170815041135` )
```

I've read I need to loop through the calculation like this

```
for i in "${array[@]}" do 
  ?
```

How do I add my array dates into the calculation?

Comment: "each has a datestamp in filename" -- what is the full filename?

Comment: XXX_1_20170830200211.bin

Comment: `filename=XXX_1_20170830200211.bin; tmp=${filename%.bin}; datestamp=${tmp##*_}` -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

Your datetimes into an array:

```
timestamps=(
    20170815041135
    20170820041135
    20170823071727
    20170826040609
    20170828050704
    20170830153011
)
```

Let's now convert those into epoch times:

```
epochs=()
for timestamp in "${timestamps[@]}"; do 
    iso8601=$(sed -r 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:\6/' <<<"$timestamp")
    epochs+=( "$(date -d "$iso8601" "+%s")" )
done
printf "%s\n" "${epochs[@]}"
```

```
1502784695
1503216695
1503487047
1503734769
1503911224
1504121411
```

Now we can iterate over them to calculate the differences. Note that bash array indices start at zero:

```
n=0
sum=0
for ((i=1; i < "${#epochs[@]}"; i++ )); do 
    ((n++, diff=(${epochs[i]} - ${epochs[i-1]}), sum+=diff))
    echo "diff $n = $diff seconds = $((diff/86400)) days"
done
echo "average = $((sum/n)) seconds = $((sum/n/86400)) days"
```

```
diff 1 = 432000 seconds = 5 days
diff 2 = 270352 seconds = 3 days
diff 3 = 247722 seconds = 2 days
diff 4 = 176455 seconds = 2 days
diff 5 = 210187 seconds = 2 days
average = 267343 seconds = 3 days
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, very kind of you to lay it out like this

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date in seconds from 1970.
Calculate the difference.
I hope that the bash date function knows to take into account the daylight saving time from that date.